# JQuery: How do I print a value in HTML when a radio button is clicked?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have three radio button's which have related values of £40, £30, £50. I want the text in the `<p>` to dynamically update to display the value of the radio button that has been clicked.

How can I do this with JQuery? Here is my code:

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>

<div class="bg-light mb-3">
  <div class="radio">
    <label class="insurance-plan">
                                     <input type="radio" name="optradio">
                                     <span class="insurance-plan-text">Basic excess</span>
                                     <span class="float-right"><span class="protection-reduced-price">£40.00</span><span class="protection-reduced-day">/day</span></span>

                                     </label>

  </div>
</div>

<div class="bg-light mb-3">
  <div class="radio">
    <label class="insurance-plan">
                                     <input type="radio" name="optradio">
                                     <span class="insurance-plan-text">Premium excess</span>
                                     <span class="float-right"><span class="protection-reduced-price">£30.00</span><span class="protection-reduced-day">/day</span></span>

                                     </label>

  </div>
</div>

<div class="bg-light mb-3">
  <div class="radio">
    <label class="insurance-plan">
                                     <input type="radio" name="optradio">
                                     <span class="insurance-plan-text">Premium excess</span>
                                     <span class="float-right"><span class="protection-reduced-price">£50.00</span><span class="protection-reduced-day">/day</span></span>

                                     </label>

  </div>
</div>

<p>You will pay an excess of [£30/40] per day.</p>
```

Comment: What do you mean by print? Can you give more detail?

Comment: Try `var radioValue = $("input[name='optradio']:checked").val();`

Comment: @DacreDenny Print means if you see in the preview the text below says "You will pay an excess of [£30/40/50] per day. I want to replace 30/40/50 by the option I chose.

Comment: @BillNathan have just provided that answer here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55505216/how-do-i-print-a-value-from-a-radio-button/55505306#55505306 hope this helps :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using jQuery, you could achieve this via the following (see comments in code snippet for detail):

```js
/* Attach click handler to radio input of each .insurance-plan */
$('.insurance-plan input[type="radio"]').click(function() {

  /* When the radio button is clicked, get it's parent element */
  const insurancePlanElement = $(this).parent();

  /* Get the .protection-reduced-price of this buttons .insurance-plan */
  const priceElement = $('.protection-reduced-price', insurancePlanElement).first();

  /* Create learn more link  */
  const learnMoreLink = $('<a>', {
      href: "someurl.com"
    })
    .text('Click here to learn more');

  /* Create span with HTML of print message */
  const message = $('<span>')
    .html("You will pay an excess of <span class='font-weight-600'>" +
      priceElement.text() +
      "</span> per day.")

  /* Update the print wrapper's element content */
  $('#printMessage')
    .empty()
    .append(message)
    .append(learnMoreLink)
});
```

```css
.font-weight-600 {
  font-weight: 600;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.0.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="bg-light mb-3">
  <div class="radio">
    <label class="insurance-plan">
      <input type="radio" name="optradio">
      <span class="insurance-plan-text">Basic excess</span>
      <span class="float-right"><span class="protection-reduced-price">£40.00</span><span class="protection-reduced-day">/day</span></span>
    </label>
  </div>
</div>

<div class="bg-light mb-3">
  <div class="radio">
    <label class="insurance-plan">
      <input type="radio" name="optradio">
      <span class="insurance-plan-text">Premium excess</span>
      <span class="float-right"><span class="protection-reduced-price">£30.00</span><span class="protection-reduced-day">/day</span></span>
</label>
  </div>
</div>

<div class="bg-light mb-3">
  <div class="radio">
    <label class="insurance-plan">
      <input type="radio" name="optradio">
      <span class="insurance-plan-text">Premium excess</span>
      <span class="float-right"><span class="protection-reduced-price">£50.00</span><span class="protection-reduced-day">/day</span></span> 
     </label>
  </div>
</div>
<p id="printMessage">
  <span>Please select an option.</span>
</p>
```

### Update

Updated script to include "learn more" link, and bold price value

Comment: What if I have multiple <p></p> in the page which <p> will it recognize? And what if I want to make "You will pay an excess of *£40.00* per day." £40.00 font-weight: 600? What if I want to add a learn more link at the end of the sentence?

Comment: I have updated the question slightly can you check, please? :)

Comment: @BillNathan I would suggest accepting the answer above if it has been helpful, and posting the updated question as a new question seeing it's diverged from the original post. I'd be happy to answer that new question if you send me a link to it :)

Comment: Here's the link to the new question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55506081/select-different-divs-on-radio-button-options :)

Answer (score 0):

Simple jQuery - when a radio button is clicked, print out the nested `span`'s `text`:

```js
$("input[type='radio']").on("click", function() {
  var value = $(this).parent().find("span > span.protection-reduced-price").text();
  console.log(value);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>

<div class="bg-light mb-3">
  <div class="radio">
    <label class="insurance-plan">
      <input type="radio" name="optradio">
      <span class="insurance-plan-text">Basic excess</span>
      <span class="float-right"><span class="protection-reduced-price">£40.00</span><span class="protection-reduced-day">/day</span></span>
    </label>
  </div>
</div>

<div class="bg-light mb-3">
  <div class="radio">
    <label class="insurance-plan">
      <input type="radio" name="optradio">
      <span class="insurance-plan-text">Premium excess</span>
      <span class="float-right"><span class="protection-reduced-price">£30.00</span><span class="protection-reduced-day">/day</span></span>
</label>
  </div>
</div>

<div class="bg-light mb-3">
  <div class="radio">
    <label class="insurance-plan">
      <input type="radio" name="optradio">
      <span class="insurance-plan-text">Premium excess</span>
      <span class="float-right"><span class="protection-reduced-price">£50.00</span><span class="protection-reduced-day">/day</span></span> 
     </label>
  </div>
</div>
<p>You will pay an excess of [£30/40] per day.</p>
```

Comment: I think the author wants the formatted message to be printed in the `<p>`, rather than the value being logged to the console