# Select different divs on radio button options

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have three radio buttons by default none of them is selected and a message saying "By selecting option 1 and 2, you reduce risk. Learn more" is displayed by default.

Now if I select option 1, "You are not liable to pay any excess fee." should replace the default text.

If I select option 2 or 3, "You will pay an excess of up to [£700 (for moderate)/1000 (for basic)] per day. Learn more" £700 will load if I chose option 2 and £1000 will load if I chose option 3 by replacing the default text.

Can someone help me how to achieve it?

Regards, Bill

```css
.font-weight-600 {
  font-weight: 600;
}
```

```html
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
 
<!-- Default Message -->
<div>By selecting option 1 and 2, you reduce risk. <a href="#">Learn more</a></div>
<!-- If I select Premium excess -->
<div>You are not liable to pay any excess fee.</div>
<!-- If I select Moderate excess or Basic excess -->
<div>You will pay an excess of <span class="font-weight-600">up to [£700 (for moderate)/1000 (for basic)]</span> per day. <a href="#">Learn more</a></div>

<div class="bg-light mb-3">
 <div class="radio">
  <label class="insurance-plan">
   <input type="radio" name="optradio">
    <span class="insurance-plan-text">Premium excess</span>
     <span class="float-right"><span class="protection-reduced-price">£30.00</span><span class="protection-reduced-day">/day</span></span>
     </label>
    </div>
   </div>
   
<div class="bg-light mb-3">
 <div class="radio">
  <label class="insurance-plan">
   <input type="radio" name="optradio">
    <span class="insurance-plan-text">Moderate excess</span>
     <span class="float-right"><span class="protection-reduced-price">£40.00</span><span class="protection-reduced-day">/day</span></span>
     </label>
    </div>
   </div>
   
<div class="bg-light mb-3">
 <div class="radio">
  <label class="insurance-plan">
   <input type="radio" name="optradio">
    <span class="insurance-plan-text">Basic excess</span>
     <span class="float-right"><span class="protection-reduced-price">FREE</span></span>
     </label>
    </div>
   </div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, I separated **Moderate** and **Basic** excess messages. Then, I added class names to your excess messages. Here is working snippet based on your code:

```js
$('input:radio[name="optradio"]').change(function(){
    $('.default-message, .excess-message').hide();
    $('.' + $(this).val()).show();
});
```

```css
.font-weight-600 {
    font-weight: 600;
}
.excess-message {
    display: none;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<!-- Default Message -->
<div class="default-message">
    By selecting option 1 and 2, you reduce risk.
    <a href="#">Learn more</a>
</div>

<!-- If I select Premium excess -->
<div class="excess-message premium">You are not liable to pay any excess fee.</div>

<!-- If I select Moderate excess -->
<div class="excess-message moderate">
    You will pay an excess of <span class="font-weight-600">up to £700</span> per day.
    <a href="#">Learn more</a>
</div>

<!-- If I select Basic excess -->
<div class="excess-message basic">
    You will pay an excess of <span class="font-weight-600">up to £1000</span> per day.
    <a href="#">Learn more</a>
</div>

<div class="bg-light mb-3">
    <div class="radio">
        <label class="insurance-plan">
            <input type="radio" name="optradio" value="premium">
            <span class="insurance-plan-text">Premium excess</span>
            <span class="float-right"><span class="protection-reduced-price">£30.00</span><span class="protection-reduced-day">/day</span></span>
        </label>
    </div>
</div>

<div class="bg-light mb-3">
    <div class="radio">
        <label class="insurance-plan">
            <input type="radio" name="optradio" value="moderate">
            <span class="insurance-plan-text">Moderate excess</span>
            <span class="float-right"><span class="protection-reduced-price">£40.00</span><span class="protection-reduced-day">/day</span></span>
        </label>
    </div>
</div>

<div class="bg-light mb-3">
    <div class="radio">
        <label class="insurance-plan">
            <input type="radio" name="optradio" value="basic">
            <span class="insurance-plan-text">Basic excess</span>
            <span class="float-right"><span class="protection-reduced-price">FREE</span></span>
        </label>
    </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

A simple approach might be to update your HTML markup to add `data-option` attributes to your radio input elements like so:

```
<input type="radio" name="optradio" data-option="1">
```

This allows you to easily determine which radio button is clicked in your script, so that you can decide what message to display to the user. Consider the script and HTML below, where messages are displayed based on their class:

```js
$('.insurance-plan input[type="radio"]').click(function() {
  
  /* Re-hide all messages */
  $("[class^='message']").hide();
  
  /* Extract the option number of this radio button */
  const option = $(this).data('option');
  
  /* Display only the message that should be shown as per the clicked radio button */
  $('.message-' + option).show();

});
```

```css
.font-weight-600 {
  font-weight: 600;
}

/* Message 1, 2 and 3 are hidden by default */
.message-1, .message-2, .message-3 {
  display:none;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
 
 
<!-- Update markup for messages -->
<div class="message-default">By selecting option 1 and 2, you reduce risk. <a href="#">Learn more</a></div>
<div class="message-1">You are not liable to pay any excess fee.</div>
<div class="message-2">You will pay an excess of <span class="font-weight-600">up to [£700 (for moderate)/1000 (for basic)]</span> per day. <a href="#">Learn more</a></div>
<div class="message-3">You will pay an excess of <span class="font-weight-600">up to [£1000 (for moderate)/1000 (for basic)]</span> per day. <a href="#">Learn more</a></div>

<div class="bg-light mb-3">
 <div class="radio">
  <label class="insurance-plan">
  
    <!-- Add data-message attribute to radio button -->
   <input type="radio" name="optradio" data-option="1">
    <span class="insurance-plan-text">Premium excess</span>
     <span class="float-right"><span class="protection-reduced-price">£30.00</span><span class="protection-reduced-day">/day</span></span>
     </label>
    </div>
   </div>
   
<div class="bg-light mb-3">
 <div class="radio">
  <label class="insurance-plan">
  
    <!-- Add data-message attribute to radio button -->
   <input type="radio" name="optradio" data-option="2">
    <span class="insurance-plan-text">Moderate excess</span>
     <span class="float-right"><span class="protection-reduced-price">£40.00</span><span class="protection-reduced-day">/day</span></span>
     </label>
    </div>
   </div>
   
<div class="bg-light mb-3">
 <div class="radio">
  <label class="insurance-plan">
  
    <!-- Add data-message attribute to radio button -->
   <input type="radio" name="optradio" data-option="3">
    <span class="insurance-plan-text">Basic excess</span>
     <span class="float-right"><span class="protection-reduced-price">FREE</span></span>
     </label>
    </div>
   </div>
```

Hope that helps!

Comment: The text `By selecting option 1 and 2, you reduce risk. Learn more` should be displayed by default. You forgot about the option 2 and 3 details (£700 for the option 2 and £1000 for the option 3)

Comment: @Dacre There's a misunderstanding. By default, "By selecting option 1 and 2, you reduce risk. Learn more" this should load. If I select option 1 (premium excess) it should load "You are not liable to pay any excess fee.". If I select between option 2 and 3, It should load "You will pay an excess of up to [£700 (for moderate)/1000 (for basic)] per day. Learn more" the only difference will be if I select option 2 it should print £700, and I select option 3 it should print £1000 the rest of the sentence remains same.

Comment: The last thing to fix is. When I select "Moderate excess" It should print, "You will pay an excess of up to [£700] per day. Learn more". If I select "Basic excess" it should print, "You will pay an excess of up to [£1000] per day. Learn more"

Comment: Updated - does that help?